# Trying to Deserialize JSON Array in to List in C#

Tags: c#, json

**I'm new to C# and I'm trying to learn JSON deserialization.**

The following code works great when I have a single JSON item:

```
var content1 = @"{""id"":7,""title"":""XYZ"",""date_of_class"":""2023-01-03T14:00:00-05:00"",""instructor"":""Teacher1"",""length"":75,""status"":""Active"",""created_on"":""2023-01-04T16:21:37-05:00"",""modified_at"":""2023-01-04T20:53:43.909660-05:00""}";
var tempObject1 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Class>(content1);
Debug.WriteLine($"**** Title: {tempObject.Title}");             // Prints Title: XYZ
Debug.WriteLine($"**** Instructor: {tempObject.Instructor}");   // Prints Instructor: Teacher1
```

Problem is that my data is an **array of JSON items** and I'm not sure how to read that.  Here's the code:

```
var content2 = @"[{""id"":6,""title"":""ABC"",""date_of_class"":""2023-01-03T14:00:00-05:00"",""instructor"":""Teacher2"",""length"":75,""status"":""Active"",""created_on"":""2023-01-04T16:21:37-05:00"",""modified_at"":""2023-01-04T20:53:43.909660-05:00""},{""id"":7,""title"":""XYZ"",""date_of_class"":""2023-01-03T14:00:00-05:00"",""instructor"":""Teacher1"",""length"":75,""status"":""Active"",""created_on"":""2023-01-04T16:21:37-05:00"",""modified_at"":""2023-01-04T20:53:43.909660-05:00""}]";
var tempObject2 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Class>(content2);    

// RECEIVE ERROR: Exception thrown: 'System.Text.Json.JsonException' in System.Text.Json.dll
```

I'm using a data model that looks like this:

```
    public class Class
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("date_of_class")]
        public string DateOfClass { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("instructor")]
        public string Instructor { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("length")]
        public int Length { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("created_on")]
        public string CreatedOn { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("modified_at")]
        public string ModifiedAt { get; set; }
    }
```

**How do I read the array of JSON data items into a List?**

Thank you for your input!

Comment: Just deserialize to `List<Class>`: `var list = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Class>>(content2);`.  Then you can do `foreach (var tempObject1 in list) { /* Print the object */ }`

Comment: @dbc Thank you!  Please post that as an answer and I'll be happy to accept it.